# Reverse Hash with MS Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I was watching a video on YouTube called '[The A4 Paper Puzzle](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SOgn6J12NWE)' in it the presenter takes a sheet of A4 paper and folds it a certain way and then asks the viewers to calculate the perimeter, but does not give the solution, instead gives a method of checking that you have the right answer using a Hash.

The sequence to know the correct answer is = Take your answer and on a calculator click sq rt 5 times, then from the result take the 6 digits on the right side of the decimal point and re-arrange them in numerical ascending order and if they equal 234477 you have the right answer.

So rather than try to calculate the perimeter I wanted to reverse the hash to get to the solution. So I fired up Excel and in A5 I entered the candidate number (say 42) and then in the B5 to F5 I started square rooting. In G5 I subtracted 1 to give me 0.123897073 which in H5 I multiplied by 1 million to give me 123897, then in I5:I10 I extracted each of the numbers. In J5:J10 I sorted the numbers using a formula so J5-1, J6=2,J7=3,J8=7,J9=8,J10=9, then finally in K5 I concatenated all the numbers to give me 123789 and placed the target 234477 in L5.

Now here is where I am stuck I assumed I could use Goal Seek to set K5 to equal 234477 by changing A5 but it won't find a solution.

I don't want to use code/macro to find the answer or manual operations like sort etc, I liked the idea of watching the Goal Seek go through and try solutions and being able 'to see' the path to the solution.

Does anyone know how I can complete this?

Formulas
A5 = User input number
B5 = SQRT(A5)
C5 = SQRT(B5)
D5 = SQRT(C5)
E5 = SQRT(D5)
F5 = SQRT(E5)
G5 = F5-1
H5 = IF(MID(G5,3,1)*1=0,G5*10000000,G5*1000000)
(LIST)I5:I10 = MID($F$5,3,1)*1  [Increment 3 by 1 per row)
J5:J10 { = INDEX(list, MATCH(SMALL(COUNTIF(list, "<"&list), ROW(1:1)), COUNTIF(list, "<"&list), 0))}
K5 = J5&J6&J7&J8&J9&J10

[image]

EDIT: Maybe I shouldn't use Goal Seek it may have limitations, even if I enter the target 123789 it still can't find the start value of 42.

Answer (score 0):

In general you should try to find an algorithm valid not only for your solution.
Try even to speed up calculation as you can.

[image: Wrong solution]

- `A5` It will keep your initial value
- `B5` `=A5^(1/32)`, yes a little of mathematics
  <sup>(SQRT(x) is equivalent to  x^1/2; do it five times means 1/2*1/2*.... = 1/32)</sup>
- `C5` `=Mod(B5,1)`
  Here you cannot simply do `1-x`: imagine if it was 2.smth or
  0.smth...

  > The MOD function returns the remainder after a number is divided by a divisor..
- `D5` `=3-TRUNC(LOG(C5,10))`
  You need to take the first digits different from zero (function Log<sub>10</sub>), and skip the `0.` of the string.
- `E5` `=MID(C5,D5,6)` Here you extract the string.
- `F5:F10` Simple indexes for the next column functions.
- `G5` `=0+MID($E$5,F5,1)`  it extract the digit in F5. Copy&Paste in `G5:G10`.
- `H5` `=LARGE($G$5:$G$10,7-F5)`  Take the `7-F5`<sup>th</sup> largest from the range `G5:G10` . Copy&Paste in `H5:H10`.
- `I5` `=H5&H6&H7&H8&H9&H10` Compose the string again
- `J5` It will keep the HASH solution to find (you called it *Target*)
- `K5` `=I5=MID(J5,1,6)` Compare the string in `I5` and *from* `J5`.

Here below the solution:

> [image]

Here a bash code for SHA256

> Here a bash code for SHA256
>         StartSeq=1 ; EndSeq=5

```
for i in $(seq $StartSeq $EndSeq) ;
 do 
   [[ $(printf "$i" | sha256sum | awk '{print $1}'| xxd -r -p | base64) \
   == "SyJ3d9TdH8Ycb4hPSGQdArTRIdP9Moywi1Ux/Kzav4o=" ]] && \
   echo "### The Solution is "$i ; 
done
```

Comment: Does this use goal seek? Because it's not working for me.

Comment: I don't have MS eXcel with me. I did with google spreadsheet. If you put a number in A5 it will check it the solution is correct in K5. I think you can use the goal seek on it.

Comment: The video sounds to me like you need to exclude all zero digits from E5

Comment: @Raystafarian Yes it does, calculating in D5 from where to start from (it cuts all the zeroes after the point... using the Log in base 10... Log_10(0.1)= -1,Log_10(0.01)= -2...)

Comment: For me it was excluding the first zero, but not if there was a second, but maybe I typed something wrong

Comment: I've tested and it worked as expected not only with the real solution and with the [_Answer to the Ultimate Question of Life_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrases_from_The_Hitchhiker's_Guide_to_the_Galaxy#Answer_to_the_Ultimate_Question_of_Life.2C_the_Universe.2C_and_Everything_.2842.29). :-D

Comment: I think, then, if you make your strings `INT()` you might be able to use goal seek with that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34969/discussion-between-hastur-and-raystafarian).

Answer (score 0):

**Thanks to Hastur** I've found a way for Goal Seek to work. It has found two solutions for me so far -

> 4 and 2340.

All right, so here we go based on [Hastur's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1032484/116196)

Again we'll start in `A5`

- **A5** = any number
- **B5** `=INT(A5)`
- **C5** `=B5^(1/32)`
- **D5** `=INT(MID(C5,FIND(".",C5,1)+1,10))`
- **E5** `=INT(IFERROR(IF(FIND("0",D5,1)<6,CONCATENATE(LEFT(D5,FIND("0",D5,1)-1),MID(D5,FIND("0",D5,1)+1,10-FIND("0",D5,1)))),LEFT(D5,6)))`
- **F5** `=INT(IFERROR(IF(FIND("0",E5,1)<=6,CONCATENATE(LEFT(E5,FIND("0",E5,1)-1),MID(E5,FIND("0",E5,1)+1,7-FIND("0",E5,1))),LEFT(E5,6)),LEFT(E5,6)))`
- **G5 to G10** are index 1,2,3,4,5,6 - they never change
- **H5 to H10** `=INT(0+MID($F$5,$G5,1))` dragged down such that `$G5` increases to 6, 7 etc.
- **I5 to I10** `=SMALL($H$5:$H$10,ROW(A1))` dragged down such that `Row(A1)` increases
- **J5** `=INT(CONCATENATE(I5,I6,I7,I8,I9,I10))`

Now you can goal seek on **J5** to *234477* by changing **A5**

[image]

---

**Solution**

> [image]